# Asynchronous cmd or readline in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, readline, nonblocking

I would like to write a simple program that both (1) produces lines of output simultaneously, and (2) accepts input from the user via a command line (via readline).  (Think of a text-mode chat client, for example.  I want to be able to compose my chat messages while still seeing incoming chat messages as they are received.) To accomplish this, I would like to be able to call readline asynchronously.

The Readline library explicitly supports this, via its [callback interface](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_41.html):

> An alternate interface is available to plain readline(). Some applications need to interleave keyboard I/O with file, device, or window system I/O, typically by using a main loop to select() on various file descriptors. To accommodate this need, readline can also be invoked as a `callback' function from an event loop. There are functions available to make this easy.

- **Is this functionality available via Python?**
- **Is it possible to use the [Cmd](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) class for such a purpose?**

Comment: What version of Python are you writing for?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.6 but would be happy for an answer working with any version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Some installations of python support the `readline` interface, some do not. The only way to find out is via testing. Does `import readline` work or raise and `ImportError`?

The python `cmd` module is intended for a totally diferent purpose involvivng making your own shells and is not helpful in this context.

Even if the `readline` module is not available, a similar task could be accomplished with threads.

Comment: I don't think "cmd"  is intended for a "totally diferent purpose".  I want cmd, but with non-blocking input.

Comment: I do have readline.  My question is how to use it to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 0):

No, `cmd`'s use of readline does not include using the callback interface. You cannot accomplish what want using that.

However, you can accomplish what you want by using [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html). Do your blocking network reads and printing of chat messages in one thread; do your blocking calls to `cmd`, the execution of cmds, and the network writes in another thread.